# Is it possible to identify beacon position with respect to user?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios7, ibeacon, ios7.1

I know it is possible to get the distance from a iBeacon to device.

Consider two beacons placed exact same distance from the device, but one is on left side and other is on right side of the device. Is it possible to identify which one is left side and which one is right side of the device.

Comment: triangulation is the key

Comment: @Daij-Djan, Are you aware of anybody who has done a writeup of a successful iBeacon triangulation/trilateration implementation?  I do not know anybody has been able to do this successfully due to the noise on the distance estimate.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot do this with standard iBeacons.

iBeacons are very simple devices that just transmit a regular "advertisement".  The way mobile devices estimate the distance to an iBeacon is simply by looking at the signal strength of these advertisements when they are received, and plugging this signal strength into a formula that converts it to an estimated distance in meters.

Because the antenna patterns on iBeacons are typically circular, there is no way to estimate the direction you are from an iBeacon.  When the mobile device estimates it is one meter away, it could be in any direction.

You might be able to make an algorithm to do something like this if you could get custom iBeacons that have a unidirectional antenna pattern.  Unfortunately, I am not aware of any that exist.

Comment: it is the same with any radio wave signal I know